# import responsible widget page for tabWidget Python

Tags: python, pyqt5

i am new in Pyqt5 and Python. i created  a tabWidget in "mainWindow"  using qtDesigner. i have created two widget called Admin.py and student.py. now can you guys tell me how to call the pages in each tab.

thanks in advnc.

**mainWindow.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from admin import Ui_Form
from student import Ui_Form

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        -----------
        -----------
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "MyApp"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Admin"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Student"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**admin.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
---------
----------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to add "pages" to a QTabWidget and those pages are in separate ui files, then you need to add them using [`addTab()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#addTab).

Since I suppose that those pages will be the only actual pages in the tab widget, you should remove the pages that Designer has created (right click on the tab, then select "Delete" from the "Page x of y..." sub menu).

Note that you seem to be trying to create your program by editing the files generated by `pyuic`, which should **never** be done, as they are only intended to be used as imported modules, and should not be edited for any reason. Read more about 
[using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) to better understand how to deal with them.

Assuming you recreate the files with pyuic and never touch those python files anymore besides overwriting them whenever you update their source ui, and that you changed the object names of the two widgets to `AdminForm` and `StudentForm`, here's an example of what you could do.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from mainWindow import Ui_MainWindow
from admin import Ui_AdminForm
from student import Ui_StudentForm


class AdminPage(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_AdminForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)


class StudentPage(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_StudentForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.adminPage = AdminPage()
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.adminPage, 'Admin')

        self.studentPage = StudentPage()
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.studentPage, 'Student')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: i did exactly what you tell me to do. first i deleted the tab from designer and regenerate the mainwindow page by pyuic5. and created a new python  file name : application.py. adding above code. project running well. problem is that if  i add one tab  it's working fine. but addidng two tab , it created problems. same page is shown.

Comment: @varatbhusan You're probably using the same files for both Admin and Student (or you're using the wrong class constructors). Ensure that they are correctly named, and that you've correctly generated the other 2 files with pyuic from the different ui sources.

Comment: work fine now. made a mistake .putting same class name "ui_form" for both admin and student. actually when  generate by using pyuic5 both class name is same "ui_form"
thanks for help

Comment: @varatbhusan that's exactly the reason for which I expressely wrote: "Assuming [...] that you changed the object names of the two widgets to `AdminForm` and `StudentForm`". You *have* to change those names and make them unique, otherwise you'll be overwriting the import since they'll have the same names. Just change their object names in Designer with appropriate names. Also, if my answer helped you to solve your problem, remember to mark it as accepted by clicking on the check symbol under the voting arrows that are on its left.

Comment: voted.this is my mailID:  bvarat2020@gmail.com.
can you please ping me. that i can show you what i am trying ato make and you can give me the right way to begin my project

Comment: hi  create a new file  "admin_main" and inherit the file admin.py which is generated from pyuic5 .
now when i try to inherit the  "admin_main" into "application.py" in tab. as like before i did than below error is showing:
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases QWidget, accMainWindow

Comment: can u please mail me into this: bvarat2020@gmail.com, that i can show you the project

Comment: @varatbhusan Sorry, but I prefer to not give answers in private. I suggest you to rebuild the files and carefully follow the procedure. If you still have problems, create a new question here on StackOverflow.