# order (MRO) :Cannot create a consistent method resolution Pyqt5 (inherit python file)

Tags: python, pyqt5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2LPx.jpg)

Hi From my previous post, [import responsible widget page for tabWidget Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61127134/import-responsible-widget-page-for-tabwidget-python), it was working fine.
now i am creating ui files and import in .py file using  uic.loadUi (without using pyuic5) as i shown in the pic.
while i trying to inherit the page into application.py it is not working. i believe i am doing wrong to apply  multiple inheritance .  i tried many approaches. but not getting success.
can anyone please solve my problem.
i even tried converting ui files using pyuic5 and inherit into application.py . but same result.
here the google drive link:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UEGw1YR7hxKhH_KK9tX8CiHMgAbEVv5W?usp=sharing

Comment: First of all, don't post code as images. Then, you're making things much more complex than they are. Both `Ui_student` and `Ui_main` you created **already** are QWidgets, creating a further subclass doesn't make any sense at all. Read again the guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) and try to understand how it works, and pay attention both to the classes those examples use *and* what they inherit from: the `Ui_*` *names* used there are python `object` classes, but if you're using loadUi you are already dealing with QWidgets.

Comment: So, not only you shouldn't probably name them like that (it's a naming convention used only for `pyuic` generated files, which you're not using), but you should also better understand how subclassing works, as in your `application.py` you're trying to create subclasses inheriting from the same ancestor: you're practically doing something like `class StundentPage(QtWidgets.QWidget, QtWidgets.QWidget)`.

Comment: okay, let me read the documentation again. thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

**mainWindow.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
from files.main_interfaces.mainWindow import Ui_MainWindow
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**mainStudent.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
from files.main_interfaces.student import Ui_Form
class stdMainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget,Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(stdMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.function1)

    def function1(self):
        print("function called")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = stdMainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

inherit both file mainWindow and mainStudent.py into App.py.

**App.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from mainAcc import MainWindow
from mainStudent import stdMainWindow

class studentPage(stdMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)


class MainWindow3(MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        # Add tab
        self.studentPage = studentPage()
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.studentPage, 'Student')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow3()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

now if i run App.py , application is running but student page is two times appears and overlapped. 
error is :
**QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to studentPage "Form", which already has a layout**

now please tell me where i did mistake!!